# How can I apply blur filter in Phaser 2.7

Tags: javascript, html-canvas, phaser, filtering, pixi.js

can somebody please tell me how can I apply filters in general, and specifically blur filters in Phaser 2.7?

The approach I found on ChatGPT is:

```
var blurYFilter = game.add.filter('BlurY');
blurYFilter.blur = 20; // Set the blur value to 20
sprite.filters = [blurYFilter];
```

But this is not working. Can you please tell me the correct way to apply filters?

I am getting this error:

```
c.Filter[a] is not a constructor
    at c.GameObjectFactory.filter
```

Comment: Same Question as on SO, and is answered: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77696819/1679286